# What is the origin and meaning of the phrase "Lambda the ultimate?"

Tags: soft-question, terminology, functional-programming, lambda-calculus

I've been messing around with functional programming languages for a few years, and I keep encountering this phrase.

I understand what lambda means, the idea of an anonymous function is both simple and powerful, but I fail to understand what "the ultimate" means in this context.

I feel like I'm missing a reference here, can anyone help?

Comment: I don't know.  But it probably relates to a series of "Lambda the Ultimate _____ " papers that are collected [here](http://library.readscheme.org/page1.html).  Whether those authors invented the phrase, or were using something older, is a question someone else will have to answer.

Comment: Aaron is right.

Comment: If @Aaron is correct, it simply raises another question.

Comment: N.B. -- This question was [also posted on programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/107687/26921), where it acquired two answers. [I answered there](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/107687/what-is-the-origin-and-meaning-of-the-phrase-lambda-the-ultimate/107704#107704) instead of here because my remarks about the meaning were merely informed speculation.

Comment: Sorry for the cross-posting, I wasn't sure which site was the better fit.